# Как в Python сравнить значения двух списков разной длины?

Tags: python, list, сравнение

У меня есть 2 списка: на 10 элементов и на 20 элементов. Причем в большом списке половина элементов дублируют значения малого списка.

Теперь мне надо сравнить значения обоих списков. И по тем строкам, **где значения совпадают**, из переменной `string_all` следует брать элемент, **индекс которого соответствует индексу проверяемого элемента малого списка**. Выбрав данный элемент из `string_all`, мне надлежит положить его в новый список `new_list`. Обращаю внимание, что сей элемент – также список.

> Например, `x_i = 0.314` и `x_j = 0.314`: в таком случае выбирается элемент (список в переменной `string_all`) с индексом `1` (т.к. `0.314` в малом списке идет под индексом `1`).

Сейчас я реализовал код, в котором перебор с ошибкой `IndexError: list index out of range` заканчивается, когда завершается длина короткого списка.

Как исправить?

Код:

```
import numpy as np

x_i_list = [(0.1*np.pi*i) for i in range(0, 10)]   # короткий список x_i
x_j_list = [(0.05*np.pi*j) for j in range(0, 20)]  # длинный список x_j
string_all = [[0.3090169943749474, -0.030248736457421654, -0.027287779377629773, 0.005632075050412966, 0.0021198112237124644, -0.0007588086390797333, -0.00013322441564495024, 8.731841055420464e-05, 4.493599625177147e-06], [0.27876825791752574, -0.05753651583505143, -0.021655704327216807, 0.00775188627412543, 0.0013610025846327312, -0.0008920330547246835, -4.5906005090745605e-05, 9.181201017938179e-05], [0.22123174208247431, -0.07919222016226823, -0.013903818053091377, 0.009112888858758161, 0.00046896952990804763, -0.0009379390598154291, 4.590600508863618e-05], [0.14203952192020608, -0.09309603821535961, -0.0047909291943332155, 0.009581858388666209, -0.0004689695299073815, -0.000892033054726793], [0.04894348370484647, -0.09788696740969283, 0.0047909291943329935, 0.009112888858758827, -0.0013610025846341745], [-0.04894348370484636, -0.09309603821535983, 0.013903818053091821, 0.007751886274124653], [-0.1420395219202062, -0.07919222016226801, 0.021655704327216474], [-0.2212317420824742, -0.05753651583505154], [-0.27876825791752574]]
# далее пытаемся сравнивать и заполнять новый список:
new_list = []
for grand_elem_j in range(len(x_j_list)):
    for grand_elem_i in range(len(x_i_list)):
        # если значения элементов обоих списков совпадают:
        if x_j_list[grand_elem_j] == x_i_list[grand_elem_i]:
            new_list.append(string_all[grand_elem_i])
```

Comment: у вас в string_all всего 9 элементов. как вы собираетесь брать оттуда значения по индексу от 0 до 9 ?

Comment: И вещественные числа так сравнивать нехорошо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у тебя string_all меньше 10 элементов, то есть когда ты находишь соответствие для 9 индекса из меньшего массива и пытаешься взять такой же элемент из string_all(где всего 9 элементов, то есть максимальный индекс 8) вылетает ошибка, я не знаю какая тут заложена логика и надо либо дополнить string_all либо уменьшить первые 2 массива

Comment: Благодарю всех за отклик. Выяснил, что в алгоритме для получения `string_all` была ошибка в одной цифре, отчего действительно, против ожидания, получал более короткий список. Все исправил, теперь длина `string_all` равна 10. При этом внес поправку в строке `for grand_elem_i in range(len(x_i_list)-1)`, скорректировав длину на единицу. И  код работает